# After updating Eclipse Luna to Eclipse Mars, red x on maven projects has appeared

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars

I just updated to Eclipse Mars from Luna and a red x is now near all my maven projects. They compile and run fine but the red x is very annoying. Anyway to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix it.

1. Right click on the project and go to "Maven"
2. Click "Update Project"
3. Click ok

The red x should go away